# Why can't I remove my Allowed Values rule from a custom field in a Work Item Template?

Tags: tfs

We have two customized Work Item Templates (Bug and Product Backlog Item (PBI)) that both contain a custom field (Change Request Number). In both templates we had added a custom ALLOWEDVALUES rule for that field, where we referenced some globallist.

Now we want to remove that restriction - we want it to be freely editable. So I removed the rule from both templates, imported them, and created both a Bug and Product Backlog Item. I then noticed the Bug working as expected (showing a simple textbox), while the PBI still showed the dropdown list containing the globallist values for that field.

I'm sure I imported the templates correctly, as changing stuff like textlabels does get reflected. What might going on here, and how can I fix the PBI templates as well?

Comment: Do you create workitems in VS or Web Access? Can you see the drop-down in both VS and Web Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can put rules on states and transitions as well. In this case there was the same Allowed Values rule applied on the "New" state in de PBI template. Removing that one solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried creating a custom field with ALLOWEDVALUES rule in PBI with TFS PowerTools, then removed the rule. The PBI work item worked as expected.

Removing a rule from a field is an easy operation, I'd like to suggest you install [TFS PowerTools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) to double check the PBI. Also, if the issue only exists in VS, try to clean the cache folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`to see whether it is helpful.

By the way, my test environment is TFS2015.3 + VS2015.3.